# R Access Field Values in a List of Reference Class Objects

Tags: r

Hopefully I can make sense of this. I am new to R. I am trying to transfer over some Python libraries and trying to wrap my head around R classes.

I have the following Reference Class:

```
curve <- setRefClass("curve",
                     fields = list(
                       runID="character", 
                       x="numeric", 
                       y="numeric"
                     ), 
                     methods = list(
                       mean = function(a, b){
                         (a + b)/2
                       },
                       calculateYCrossover = function(leftBound, rightBound, target, upDown){
                         i <- 0
                         for (xPoint in x){
                           i<-i+1
                           if (xPoint >= leftBound & xPoint <= rightBound){
                             if (upDown == "up"){
                               if (y[i] >= target & y[i-1] < target){
                                 xCoord <- xPoint
                                 yCoord <- y[i]
                                 result <- 1
                               }
                             }
                             if (upDown == "down"){
                               if (y[i] <= target & y[i-1] > target){
                                 xCoord <- xPoint
                                 yCoord <- y[i]
                                 result <- 1
                               }
                             }
                           }
                         } 
                         return(xCoord)
                       }
                       
                     )
                    )
```

So I am creating a list of all all curves in a file directory. I open a directory, and for each file in the directory, create a new curve object, assign field values, then append that new curve object to my list of curves.

```
nm <- list.files(path="C:/Users/C176616/OneDrive - Eli Lilly and Company/PAM R/PAM R/data")

setwd("./data")

curves <- c()

for (filen in nm){
  mCurve <- curve$new()
  rawCurve <- read_csv(filen, na = "empty", skip = 278)
  mCurve$runID <- filen
  mCurve$x <- head(rawCurve$mm, -1)
  mCurve$y <- head(rawCurve$N, -1)
  curves <- append(curves, mCurve)
}
```

In the environment explorer, everything looks correct. I can see my list, and I can see each curve object with fields runID, x, and y all populated with the correct data.

How can I access an individual curve's field value?

`curve[1]$runID` returns NULL.

but if I print `curve[1]`, I can see an object of Reference class 'curve' with 3 fields ..$ runID:

Any ideas on why each field would return NULL?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `curve[[1]]$runID`. You are probably creating a list. Using `[ ]` only subsets the list while `[[ ]]` extracts the element from the list

Comment: That did it! Seems like such a simple concept, but never would have thought to try that! Thank you!